# Get logged in user info - call to undefined function (2)

Tags: php, wordpress, function, call, undefined

I'm reposting this question because the problem wasn't solved.
In a relevant question the answer below may be the solution.

> Apparently this is happening because the file /wp-includes/pluggable which contains the    function doesn't get loaded until after the plugins are loaded.
>   Indeed it is. So wrap whichever thing you're doing in a function, and hook it onto the plugins_loaded or init hook. (see the wp-settings.php file)

Where exactly do I write the add_action('plugins_loaded','my_function'); command?
In the "wp-settings file", the "pluggable" or my own php file?
All I want to do is to display the user info in a php file which is loaded in a page in wordpress,but I'm constantly getting the same error "call to undefined function".
I've tried including the relevant php file, still doesn't work.

```
 <?php 
 global $current_user;
 get_currentuserinfo();
 echo $current_user->user_login;
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you!!

```
require (ABSPATH . WPINC . '/pluggable.php');
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
echo $current_user->user_login;
```

All you do is include the pluggable.php file in your plugin.

Comment: Including the `pluggable.php` file directly in a plugin is a bad idea if you plan to use the plugin along with other plugins. The `pluggable.php` file contains functions which are allowed to be user-defined. It does this by checking if a function has been defined, and if not, the function is created. If you include this file into your plugin, and you have other plugins which load after yours which need to define a custom version of these functions, their function definition will fail and cause a fatal error.